# Timer - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a timer in below function. How to change seconds for a minute and seconds? In present function, the timer counting only seconds and milliseconds.

```
if (timer === 1) {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    the_timer = setInterval(function() {
        var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
        finished_time = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3);
        $("#timer").text(finished_time);
    }, 44);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function getTimeStr does this. It even formats it nicely so 3 seconds will be displayed as `0:03`, 32 as `0:32` and 71 seconds as `1:11`.

```js
function getTimeStr(milliseconds) {
  var minutes = milliseconds / 60000;
  var intMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  var seconds = Math.floor((minutes - intMinutes) * 60);
  
  return intMinutes + ':' + (seconds < 10 ? ('0' + seconds.toFixed(0)) : seconds.toFixed(0));
}



var startTime = new Date();
setInterval(function() {
  var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
  console.log(getTimeStr(elapsedTime));
}, 100);
```